# Wordpress function.php wp_enqueue_script doesn't work

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to integrate jquery into my wordpress theme. I have integrated this code into my function.php but it doesn't work. Can anyone see the problem? Thanks.

```
//Enqueue Child Styles & Scripts on the Front-End
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    wp_enqueue_style('nebula-child'); //Stylesheets
    wp_enqueue_script('nebula-main'); //Scripts
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom.js', array ( 'jquery', '3.3.2'), '', true);
}, 327);
```

My custom.js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Comment: you could click the network tab of developer tools and check if custom.js did loaded

Comment: unfortunately it is not loaded

Comment: Do you have any 404 error not found for your custom.js file? Are you sure the file is located correctly in this path? Futhermore, could you give us a link to your domain - site?

Comment: I had no errors related to this problem in the console, nor 404 errors. As Howard said, it was enough not to specify "jquery" in my wp_enqueue_ script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Enqueue is wrong.  Your enqueue script says that a script named `3.3.2` is a dependency and won't load your script unless it finds a script by that handle.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom.js', array ( 'jquery'), '3.3.2', true);
```

3.3.2 would be YOUR script version, if your intention is to use the jQuery version... don't.

`wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', string[] $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )`

Comment: Thanks Howard, the solution you suggested seems to work. I simply removed "array ('jquery', '3.3.2')" in my wp_enqueue_script

Comment: You want  `array('jquery')` just note the other value